Can Deactivate Route Guard
I Want to implement can Deactivate Route Guard for my storefront while filling forms in some of the pages.But when I try to implement it with the Guards array it is not working and throwing some console error.How can I Implement can deactivate functionality in my storefront
I tried to Implement can deactivate in order prevent user navigating to different pages while he partially filled the form.I want to show him a alert before he is leaving the current route.
